# Can you access an svn dump file like an archive?

Tags: svn, svndump

I was wondering how (if possible) i can view/extract the contents of an SVN dump file (w/o importing it into svn)

Thanks.. :-)

Answer (score 4):

No, the Subversion dump file format isn't really set up for that at all. There's no index, no way to look up specific files inside the dump file, and (there are a few different dump file formats) I think deltas are often stored in the dump file.

The best way to get files out of a Subversion dump file is to load the dump into a Subversion repository (even just a temporary one). In this way, Subversion will recreate all the indexes and load the content into a form that is appropriate for online random access.